Does hematoxylin interact with histones or with nucleic acids?
As far as I understand, at physiological pH, the phosphate groups in the structure of nucleic acids are deprotonated, therefore, are conjugate bases. The histones they interact with are positively charged. Hematoxylin is a basic dye that stains acidic/basophilic structures, so I would not expect it to interact with the conjugate bases.
My question is: at normal pH, would hematoxylin interact with the protonated histones or the nucleic acids?
I tried looking this up but found contradictory information:

"Hematoxylin, not a dye itself, produces the blue Hematin via an oxidation reaction with nuclear histones causing nuclei to show blue."


"Previous investigators have disagreed about whether hemalum stains DNA or its associated nucleoproteins. [...] Staining experiments with DNA, histone and DNA + histone mixtures support the theory that DNA, not histone, is progressively colored by hemalum."


"Haematoxylin is used to dye cell nuclei. It binds to histones via the mordant."


"Hematoxylin has a deep blue-purple color and stains nucleic acids by a complex, incompletely understood reaction."

I would really appreciate if someone could clarify this for me, I'm a bit confused.

What is the chemical structure of hematoxylin? You are focusing on a single aspect of its chemistry, but that may not be what’s important.
